# Why does one 500W GPU run on a 220W supply while another does not?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, power-supply, gpu

I have a GTX[0] 1070(500W) working on a Dell[1] Power Supply (apparently 220W).

Another GPU with the same power specs is **not working**: GTX[3] 1080 (500W) returns `NVRM: GPU 0000:05:00.0: GPU does not have the necessary power cables connected.` as result of `sudo dmesg |grep NVRM`

**Why is one working and the other is not**?

The gpu's are attached to a notebook using a pci-e adapter[3]

---

[0] https://www.gigabyte.com/Graphics-Card/GV-N1070G1-GAMING-8GD-rev-10/sp#sp

[1] AC/DC Adapter DA-2 Series MK394 Model D220P-01 Output 12V 18A

[2] https://www.palit.com/palit/vgapro.php?id=2609&lang=en&pn=NEB1080T15P2-1040G&tab=sp

[3] https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32824725772.html

#### Remarks

The power supply powers only the gpu, nothing else

Comment: You've listed the 1070 twice, but best guess is not the total power requirement but the power per rail that's coming up short. Either way, once you ramp up the performance on either of them, the machine is likely to fall over.

Comment: The GPU does not use '500w' itself but rather that the overall recommendation for a system with a video card of that type installed.  I believe the 1070 pulls about 150w at load, so most likely it is something with the power connection on the second card, or the strange 3rd party adapter you're using with a (possibly proprietary) Dell PSU.

Comment: You listed the same card twice making it impossible to answer your question

Comment: So sorry for all your inconvenience, fixed the 2nd gpu's url: https://www.palit.com/palit/vgapro.php?id=2609&lang=en&pn=NEB1080T15P2-1040G&tab=sp

Answer (score 0):

The specs for the
[GEFORCE GTX 10 SERIES](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/10-series/)
say this:

```
GTX 1080
Graphics Card Power [W] : 180 W
Recommended System Power (W) : 500 W

GTX 1070
Graphics Card Power [W] : 180 W - 150 W
Recommended System Power [W] : 500 W
```

If the GTX 1070 only needs 150 W at full load, it can work with a 220W power supply.
However, that would mean that the rest of the system is drawing very little power,
or that the 220W power supply performs above its specs.

The GTX 1080 needs 180W at full load, but the rest of the system needs to draw
less than 320W. In addition, many power supplies rated at 500W actually deliver
much below their rating.

It is possible that you were lucky with one power supply and unlucky with another.
In any case, don't use under-powered power supplies if you care about your
hardware.

Comment: Thank you. The power supply powers only the gpu, nothing else

Comment: How is that possible? Is it a custom-built computer?

Comment: [3]: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32824725772.html

Comment: In that case, the 500W power supply is either not 500W, is perhaps old and tired, or the error message is wrong and the video driver just doesn't understand this setup.

Comment: The power supply is 220W

Comment: Only good quality power supplies really live up to their rating. For example, I have met a 500W supply that couldn't do 450W. 220W is perhaps too near to 180W. You should always use a power supply leaving a large margin for error.